# Ubuntu Cannot Connect to Internet via Ethernet Connection

Tags: internet

I am currently running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS on my Macbook Pro.  I connect it directly to my home modem via an ethernet connection.  A few days ago, I suddenly lost connection to the internet.  I ran the sudo ping command in Terminal and got a message that read “Temporary failure in name resolution” which confirms the lack of internet connection.

Here’s the odd part: I connect my iPhone directly to the same modem with an ethernet connection as well using a Belkin adapter and the internet on this phone runs perfectly fine (I’m writing this message from it).  This rules out issues with my ISP or the modem itself.

Here is what I’ve tried so far but didn’t resolve the issue:

- Changed the ethernet port on the back of the modem (one of the ports could have been defective)
- Connecting via wifi
- Ran ClamAV to ensure no infections were on my computer
- Ran BleachBit to clean up files and clear cache/cookies

I can’t seem to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: that is, no internet through cable and wifi? but can you ping your router/modem? normally, connected devices receive private ip addresses or real ip?

Comment: To check connection more info is needed. Start with commands: `ip a; ip r; cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Attach results to your question.

Comment: You might consider voting their answer if it helped you. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

This worked flawless after reboot:

Cannot explain why this was necessary, but the solution came down to ensuring that the wired interface was "managed". I changed /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf from:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma
```

to:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma,except:type:ethernet
```

Comment: Please be a little careful with copying and pasting answers across AU, there is a risk that such an answer will not be a perfect fit to each question it is applied to...

Comment: I tried this and it worked! Also no need to reboot just ```sudo service network-manager restart``` in the end

Comment: Works great in Kubuntu 22.04.01 (jammy). Thank you!

Comment: Anyone has any clue what does this command *actually* do?

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

add

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

press ctrl+O then ctrl+x.
type

```
nslookup google.com
```

does it work now?

Comment: I see “nameserver 127.0.0.53 “. Then the line below that reads “options edns0 trust-ad”.  Do I overwrite 127.0.0.53 with 8.8.8.8?

Comment: yes please. please change that line

Comment: no problem. just add this line to that file and save it: nameserver 8.8.8.8  thats all

Comment: When I type ctrl+O, I get a line that reads “File Name to Write: /etc/resolv.conf” Ctrl+X does nothing but make an error noise

Comment: edit file, type ctrl+O, press enter, type ctrl+x.

Comment: you may also test your connection with ping -c 1 google.com command. you may also need a restart after editing the file

Comment: My goodness!  It worked!  Could you explain exactly what happened?  I’ll be sure to archive your answers in a document!

Comment: So easy. It is a common problem. I understood your problem within only 2 seconds. Some systems always change resolv.conf file. this file contains our DNS ip. we cant connect to internet without a DNS. so we have to type an exact DNS ip. 8.8.8.8 is Google's public DNS

Comment: You’ve been very helpful.  I have used the ip addresses 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1 to route DNS requests through Cloudfare’s service in the past.  Is there a way I can use those addresses?

Comment: 1.1. 1.1 is a public DNS resolver operated by Cloudflare. so you can use it. no problem. just try. if you have any problem, just change the ip from resolv.conf. that's your ubuntu!

Comment: Thank you very much for your extremely prompt assistance.  I hope I’ll be able to pay it forward to another someday.